# Handling two functions with one event. Corona SDK

Tags: events, lua, coronasdk

Currently googled myself insane just to get an answer on a pretty simple (I hope) way to access two or more functions at the touch of a single `EventListener`.

Found this

```
 local touchHandler = function(event)
    if event.phase == "began" then
       local t = event.target
        print( "param1=" .. t.param1 .. ", param2=" .. t.param2 .. ", param3=" .. t.param3 )
    end 
  end

  local loadServerButton = display.newRect(0, 0, 50, 50)
  loadServerButton:setFillColor(0, 0, 0)
  loadServerButton.x=  _W/2     
  loadServerButton.y=  _H/1.35
  loadServerButton.param1 = timestampWrite  
  loadServerButton.param2 = downloadServerAPI   
  loadServerButton.param3 = downloadUserAPI 
  loadServerButton:addEventListener("touch", touchHandler)
```

But have trouble managing it to work, by receiving 
*"runtime error attempted to concetrate field 'param3' (a function value)"* and so on.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your params are functions, not strings.  (Why do you want to display functions?)  One can't concatenate functions.  Convert them to strings prior to concatenation: `"param1="..tostring(t.param1)..`

Comment: Well.. I don't know...
What other way can I call all the 3 functions with one eventlistener?

Comment: To call a function you must append parentheses to function name: `functionname()`

Comment: function loadFuntions(event)
 timestampWrite()
timestampWrite2()
end

Somthing like that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming timestampWrite functions are defined like this:

```
local timestampWrite = function()
    --some code here
end
```

This is the code:

```
local touchHandler = function(event)
    if event.phase == "began" then
       local t = event.target
        print( "param1=" .. t.param1() .. ", param2=" .. t.param2() .. ", param3=" .. t.param3() )
    end 
  end

  local loadServerButton = display.newRect(0, 0, 50, 50)
  loadServerButton:setFillColor(0, 0, 0)
  loadServerButton.x=  _W/2     
  loadServerButton.y=  _H/1.35
  loadServerButton.param1 = timestampWrite  
  loadServerButton.param2 = downloadServerAPI   
  loadServerButton.param3 = downloadUserAPI 
  loadServerButton:addEventListener("touch", touchHandler)
```

More info:

- **http://lua-users.org/wiki/FunctionsTutorial**
- http://lua-users.org/wiki/TablesTutorial